# Laravel DOMPDF: how to load image from storage folder?

Tags: php, image, laravel, dompdf

An image stored in the `/storage/app/` folder of [Laravel 5.2](http://laravel.com/docs/5.2) isn't being rendered into [DOMPDF](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf). I receive an error saying: `image not found or type unknown`.

The image's path is `storage/app/v6_dashboard.png` and I tried these:

```
<img src="/media/v6_dashboard.png" />
<img src="media/v6_dashboard.png" />
<img src="http://localhost:8000/media/v6_dashboard.png" />
```

which use this route:

```
Route::get('/media/{img}', function ($img) {
  $image = Image::make(Storage::disk('local')->get($img));
  return Response::make($image->encode('jpg'), 200, ['Content-Type' => 'image/jpeg']);
});
```

Note that I have this config set: `"DOMPDF_ENABLE_REMOTE" => true`

It works in a typical HTML view but not in DOMPDF. Is there a fundamental incompatibility or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you tried: `$image = Image::make(storage_path('app/' . $img));`?

Comment: @tptcat the route itself works in an HTML view. Do you mean your syntax would be better for DOMPDF specifically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I bypassed the route and used a `str_replace` to switch `/media/` to the absolute path like so:

```
str_replace('/media/', '../storage/app/', $link);
```

Slightly counter-intuitive to go from `public` to `storage` in the HTML but it seems to be the only way for DOMPDF to render the image. Also found out that DOMPDF won't render remote images over HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

you need to reference the public path of your image. So if 'image.jpg' is in your public/images folder and stored in a variable called $image, you can do something like:

```
<img src="{{ public_path() . $image }}">
```

dompdf needs the absolute path on the server, not what the client would see!

Comment: This works for img tags, but when trying to use it in background-image css prop doesn't work. Any advice?

Comment: what do you mean like, what if accessed by css?

just put your image into **public/images/**


`.my-css-class{
    background-image: url("/images/file-name.png") 
}`

Comment: or inside html tag just,

`<div style="background-image: url('{{ asset('/images/'. $image) }}');" >`

Comment: My bad, the post says public_path, and i have my images in the storage paths, and i don't want them to be publicly accessible, and thus i need to use full paths to achieve it, but the only way i got it to work, is with laravel storage, get the file and pass it into the view base64 encoded

Comment: ummm, have you read this doc? https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem#configuration
your file will be saved in the storage folder.

Comment: Yeah, but my files are not being saved to be publicly acessible, when i saw the question i didn't notice you had `public_path()` instead of `storage_path()`. My bad

Comment: oh i see, just upload your file into storage folder. `storage/app/public/images`


`<img src="{{ asset('storage/images/'.$image) }}" />`
then

Comment: Yes, but that is in the "public" folder, i wanted the files to only be accessible if the person trying to reach them is authorized, I ended up fetching the file in the controller and returning it as a base64 to blade. https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/1683

Answer (score 1):

Getting and using the absolute path simply did not work for me. My image showed in the pdf only when I used base64 encoding:

```
$fullpath = storage_path('app/public/'.$tprofile->profilepic); 

<img 
  class="w-48 mr-6 mb-6"
  src="data:image/png;base64,
  <?php echo base64_encode(file_get_contents($fullpath)); ?>"
  width="150px"
/>
```

Comment: I had to use this solution. It was working locally using just the path, but on the server it would not show the image, even though the path was correct and the file was where it was supposed to be with the correct rights. No clue why that doesn't work.