# Cant Load Image Using Dompdf Laravel 9

Tags: laravel, dompdf

the image when i run without domPDF will come out, but if i use domPDF its say like this
[image]

this is my html code

```
<img src="{{public_path('assets/img/logoprov.png')}}" height="100" width="100">
<img src="{{public_path('img/logoprov.png')}}" height="100" width="100">
<img src="{{asset('img/logoprov.png')}}" height="100" width="100">
```

this is my controller code

```
$surat = Surat::find($id);
view()->share('surat',$surat);
$pdf = PDF::loadView('sekretariat.pdf.index',compact('surat'));
return $pdf->download('pdf_file.pdf');
```

Comment: Don't post ALLCAPS, it's considered shouting/rude.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel DOMPDF: how to load image from storage folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37079529/laravel-dompdf-how-to-load-image-from-storage-folder)

Comment: im sorry @brombeer

Comment: i dont understand where i must put the code in there answer @PunitGajjar

Comment: Where exactly is the image stored?

Comment: ..\public\assets\img\logoprov.png @StewieSWS

Comment: try putting the image in public directory and called it directly for test, `<img src="img/logoprov.png" height="100" width="100">`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1st you need to set the tempDir and chroot from you controller.

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('sekretariat.pdf.index',$surat)->setOptions([
            'tempDir' => public_path(),
            'chroot' => public_path()
        ]);
```

And in your dompdf view page load the image as:

```
<img src="{{ public_path('assets/img/logoprov.png') }}" alt="Logo">
```